# Как сделать так, чтобы после исчезновения объекта, он появлялся снова через некоторое время?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

При соприкосновении с "Игроком", "Монетка" должна исчезнуть, но через некоторое время снова появиться на этом же месте. Никак не получается это реализовать.

Пробовал через корутину - не работает.

```
public GameObject coinEffect;
public int coinsCount;
public Text coins;
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(coinsTake());
        coinsCount += 1;
        coins.text = " " + coinsCount.ToString();
        Instantiate(coinEffect, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
IEnumerator coinsTake() 
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: А как пробовали корутину? Может приложить код?

Comment: Код изменил, способ не рабочий этот:(

Comment: А в чём заключается нерабочесть? Объект не появляется? Или в чём? А если сделать  `StartCoroutine(coinsTake());` **после** `gameObject.SetActive(false);` ?

Comment: Корутина не будет работать, если объект не активен

Comment: Если у вас есть время могу в дискорде объяснить

Comment: Тут не просто объяснить

Answer (score 3):

Вы не сможете стартовать корутину из скрипта который прикреплен к неактивному объекту. Ну, почти...

`StartCoroutine` - метод, который прикреплён к классу `MonoBehaviour`. Когда вам нужно стартова корутину на деактивированном объекте, вам нужно *сослаться* на `MonoBehaviour` объекта, который имеет активный `GameObject`

Парочка способов сделать это:

**1**. Использовать существующий объект, который вряд ли будет деактивирован. Например можно использовать камеру. Например вот так:

```
// Деактивировать текущий GameObject
gameObject.SetActive(false);
// Найти камеру
MonoBehaviour camMono = Camera.main.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>();
// Использовать её для запуска корутины
camMono.StartCoroutine(Load());
```

---

**2**. Прикрепить скрипт к пустому `GameObject` и этот скрипт будет контролировать (или будет способен активировать/деактивировать)  другие объекты, в числе которых ваш.

Пример: скрипт с корутиной, которую вы планируете запустить на неактивном объекте (прикрепите её к объекту)

```
public class YourDeactivatableScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public IEnumerator coinsTake()
    {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Теперь, предположим, вы хотите деактивировать `GameObject` по имени *"Cube"*, который содержит `YourDeactivatableScript`. Создайте пустой `GameObject` и прикрепите к нему скрипт:

```
public class LoadFuncCallerScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject targetObject;

    public void Start()
    {
         // Найти GameObject, который надо деактивировать
        targetObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        // Деактивировать его
        targetObject.SetActive(false);
        // Взять его компонент/скрипт
        YourDeactivatableScript script = targetObject.GetComponent<YourDeactivatableScript>();
        // Сделать старт корутины за счёт его MonoBehaviour
        StartCoroutine(script.coinsTake());
    }
}
```

Корутина теперь запустится за счёт другого скрипта на другом объекте ( `LoadFuncCallerScript`).

---

**3**. Ещё вариант содержать какой-нибудь общий менеджер объектов с общим скриптом. Где есть словарь или список, в который добавляются объекты при инстанициировании и удаляются при уничтожении. Т.к. он будет общий для объектов, то и некоторые методы можно расположить в нём (активацию/деактивацию). В нужный момент там запускается метод `temporaryDisable(gameObject, time)`, в который передаётся объект и время. Дальше этот объект ищется скриптом в словаре/списке и делает с ним что хочется, в данном случае: деактивация -> реактивация через установленное время

Comment: можно сделать намного проще - отключать рендерер и коллайдер. И тогда не нужно пытаться бороться с ветряными мельницами)

Comment: Есть кнопка ответ) ну или дополнить)

Comment: твой ответ вполне хорош почему я за него проголосовал) Просто уточнил что есть пути по-проще)

Comment: @Andrew ну это бы тоже оформить в ответ)) Вот я и предлагаю)) Мне лень дописывать это  :DDD

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `gameObject.SetActive(...);`, используй `SetVisible(...);` и корутина заработает.

```
private void SetVisible (bool visible) {
    GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = visible;
    GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Смог реализовать это с помощью Invoke.

```
public GameObject coinEffect;
public int coinsCount;
public Text coins;
void Start()
{
    
}

void Update()
{
    
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        coinsCount += 1;
        coins.text = " " + coinsCount.ToString();
        Instantiate(coinEffect, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Invoke("SpawnCoin", 2f);
    }
}

public void SpawnCoin() 
{
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что задали вопрос вчера и вчера же САМИ ЖЕ дали на него ответ?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Бывает такое. У меня пару раз было так, что я не мог найти инфу по своей проблеме, задавал вопрос, а потом чудесным образом меня осеняло и я мог даже спустя 10 минут ответ написать))

Comment: В таком случае можно попробовать взглянуть на вопрос новым взглядом: полезен ли он для сообщества. Возможно ваш вопрос о включении-отключении объекта и полезен, но если вы уже с НОВЫМИ знаниями сами понимаете, что вопрос бессмысленен, то возможно его будет лучше в некоторых случаях удалить, а не добавлять свой вопрос. Хотя я не говорю именно про этот вопрс.